# $.get and get value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function get(){
      $.get('/get.php', function(data) {
          alert('one: ' + data)
          return data;
      });
  }

  var test = get();
  alert('two:' + test);
```

In get.php is:

```
<?php echo "number"; ?>
```

why one alert show me
**one: number**

but two alert show me
**two: undefined**

How can i get this value outside function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$.get` call is asynchronous. That means that you pass it a callback (your `function(data) { ... }`, which gets executed with the result from the call. You can't `return` from inside that callback - when it is executed, your outer function (doing the `$.get`) has already returned. Instead, try something like this:

```
// callback will be executed with the response from your GET request
function get(callback){
    $.get('/get.php', callback);
}

// Call get with a callback receiving the response
get(function(data) {
    alert('two:' + data);
});
```

This is a pattern you will have to get used to when writing javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return data` is returning from the ajax anonymous function, not from the get() function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when this statement is called, the function get() has already returned **before** the callback of $.get() has been executed. Keep in mind that ajax requests are **asynchronous**.

What are the execution steps:

1. Call get()
2. Ajax request with $.get() is initiated
3. get() returns
4. ajax request ends and callback of $.get() is executed

To handle this case, you would typically pass the callback to execute as a parameter:

```
function get(callback) {
    $.get('/get.php', function(data) {
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```